# Asynchronous reading text from image with Tesseract?

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, ocr, tesseract

is it possible to get text from images with tesseract asynchronously? 
id love to give users to cancel the scanning if it takes much time.

```
char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
```

locks the screen until OCR finishes.

Comment: Blocks don't have a built in method to stop them, you would have to write this manually, or try using an NSOperationQueue that has a method `cancelAllOperations`. This website has a good write up on them http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/

Comment: Please post a *new* question for well, a new question, instead of editing it into an existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in a background thread will let the user interface continue receiving requests. Try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
});
```

Comment: thank you.but i have another problem now. while ocr is running if user taps the Back button,it crashes.i think i must kill the all the works.here is my code: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        tesseract->Recognize(NULL);
        char* utf8Text = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ocrProcessingFinished:)
                               withObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:utf8Text]
                            waitUntilDone:NO];
        delete [] utf8Text;
    });

Comment: Try using the debugger to check the contents of the object passed to the ocrProcessingFinished method and check it isn't nil.